# Mysqli Prepare Statements + Binding Order BY

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am having a small issue with the mysqli_stmt prepare function. Here is my query:

```
$params = array(
    "sisi",
    "some_string",
    5000,
    "date_added DESC"
);

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM scenes
        WHERE scene_title LIKE ?
        AND scene_id > ?
        ORDER BY ?
        LIMIT ?";
```

Now when i bind the params to the array like this (i have a valid mysqli_stmt object instantiated):

```
call_user_func_array(array($this->mysql_stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
```

The order by is not binded. I read on php.net (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

> The markers are legal only in certain
> places in SQL statements. For example,
> they are allowed in the VALUES() list
> of an INSERT statement (to specify
> column values for a row), or in a
> comparison with a column in a WHERE
> clause to specify a comparison value.
>
> However, they are not allowed for
> identifiers (such as table or column
> names), in the select list that names
> the columns to be returned by a SELECT
> statement, or to specify both operands
> of a binary operator such as the =
> equal sign.

Is there a way around this or am i going to have to use mysql_real_escape_char() for the ORDER BY clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the php.net link you found states, you cannot use bind variables for identifiers. You'll need a workaround. `mysql_real_escape_char` would certainly be one way.

Comment: Bah, yeah, i will just force the app developer to use functions of my db class to set these attributes. I wanted to make mysqli prepare statements handle all sanitization of user defined input.

Comment: May I ask you to delete this answer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @YourCommonSense ...why?