# SQL ORDER BY using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've tried all different kinds of variations of this code and can't get it to work, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
if(isset($_GET['s']) And isset($_GET['o'])) {
    if(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET['s'])) === 's') $sortingby = 'sender';
    if(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET['s'])) === 't') $sortingby = 'title';
    if(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET['s'])) === 'd') $sortingby = 'timestamp';
    if(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET['o'])) === 'a') $orderingby = 'ASC';
    if(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET['o'])) === 'd') $orderingby = 'DESC';
    echo '<br />';
    echo $sortingby;
    echo $orderingby;
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE
                                    receiver = :id AND rhide = 0 
                                    ORDER BY :sortingby :orderingby
                                    ");
$stmt->execute(array(
                                ':id'=>$id,
                                ':sortingby'=>$sortingby,
                                ':orderingby'=>$orderingby
                                ));
$messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The variables are assigned correctly when I echo them out, it just seems like my content is being ignored

Comment: what else would I need @YourCommonSense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these links:

> [Mysqli Prepare Statements + Binding Order BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741845/mysqli-prepare-statements-binding-order-by)
>
> As the php.net link you found states, you cannot use bind variables
>   for identifiers. You'll need a workaround. `mysql_real_escape_char`
>   would certainly be one way.

... and ...

> [How do I use pdo's prepared statement for order by and limit clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683576/how-do-i-use-pdos-prepared-statement-for-order-by-and-limit-clauses)
>
> For this reason the ORDER BY fields should form part of the SQL string
>   passed into the `prepare()` method, rather than being bound to the
>   query prior to `execute()`.

==========================================================

ADDENDUM:

Since you're already effectively validating the column names and "ASC/DESC" clause before your "prepare", there's no danger of SQL Injection.

I'd just build the string:

```
$sql = 
  "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE " .
  "receiver = :id AND rhide = 0 " .
  "ORDER BY " . $sortingby . " " . $orderingby;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Hi @paulsm4 your comment told me how it's not possible, however the workaround of mysql_real_escape_string requires a direct connection to the mysql database, and does not work with PDO.  Are there any other work arounds?

Comment: Hi - See my addendum above

Comment: May I ask you two questions? 1. Why you're trying to answer questions in the area you have no idea in? 2. Would you please completely delete that statement on "mysql_real_escape_char" along with accompanying link?

Answer (score 2):

Only data can be bound with placeholders,column or table names cannot be bound.