# Are back-ticks sufficient to escape user input for table columns?

Tags: php, mysql

For example:

```
$qry=  "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `$_GET[orderBy]` ASC ;" ;
```

Would that leave it open to any vulnerabilities?

Comment: No, backticks isn't enough, use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). Backticks only ensures you haven't used a [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), or your table/columns contain spaces/hyphens.

Comment: 2k rep, you should be able to answer this your self.

Comment: How would the SQL database differentiate between your backticks and the ones coming in through the $_GET variable?

Comment: Yes it leaves vulnerabilities: `$_GET[orderBy] = 1, (select case when (1=1) then 1 else 1*(select table_name from information_schema.tables)end)=1 --`

Comment: Plus the fact that `$_GET[orderBy]` will issue a warning message unless `orderBy` is defined as a constant

Comment: @MarkBaker Good point and catch.

Comment: @Fred-ii- but how would one use a prepared statement for a column name when placeholders become encapsulated in quotes? `order by ? = order by 'column name' will not work`

Comment: @MarkBaker and @ fred @ mario is correct

Comment: Then I stand corrected.

Comment: Why would you want to use `$_GET[orderBy]` in the first place? Why not just assign a variable to it, escape it then use `ORDER BY $var`. Ask the person who gave you an "answer". It'd be nice to see that person get involved in this convo ;)

Comment: Whitelist the possible values for your orderBy; whoever submits the form could easily mistype and cause the query to error, which looks decidedly unprofessional

Comment: Reference for [SQL injection in order by clause](http://www.notsosecure.com/blog/2008/08/01/injection-in-order-by-clause/)

Comment: Have a look at the Q&A's in http://stackoverflow.com/q/19083323/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2683576/ - That should shed a bit more light on the subject ;) There are a few examples using PDO prepared statements and `:` placeholders.

Comment: thanks @Fred-ii- and @ mark for the useful references

Comment: You're very much welcome Andrew, *cheers*.

Comment: @MarkBaker You're wrong about `$_GET[orderBy]`. When used in a double-quoted string, array indices do not need to be quoted